# Windowed subtraction of vectors that are not same size and then finding the mean of results

Tags: matlab, vector, vectorization

Good day,

I have a question what I want to achieve without the loop if possible. As title says I need to do windowed subtraction of vectors that are not same size and then finding the mean of results.

As example, let say that we have vector a = [2 3 4 5 6] and vector b = [1 2]. 
Program will have to move window with smaller numbers of elements (in this example vector b) over bigger one (vector a) and make operations on that way so it starts in first two elements in vector a and make subtraction with vector b and then sum results and find mean. 
In this example it will just make calculation of subtraction 2-1 = 1, 3-2 = 1, summing results 1+1=2 and divide them with 2 (because vector b is that size). Final result is 1. 
Then we move window on second elements of vector a (value 3 and 4 there, or index 2 and 3) and repeat process to the last elements of vector a.
For final result we need to get vector c who consist of elements [1 2 3 4] for this example. 
Is this possible to do without looping because I have data sets over 10k of size. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can solve it with only one loop, iterating through "b" (two loops in your example).

Declare vectors (as columns! This is needed for matlabs computations to work)

```
a = [2 3 4 5 6]'; 
b = [1 2]';
```

Declare matrix for computed results. Each column represents subtractions of elements in "a" with one of the elements in "b".

```
c = zeros(length(a)-length(b)+1,length(b));
for k = 1:length(b)
    c(:,k) = a(k:length(a)-length(b)+k)-b(k);
end
```

Now just sum the elements in "c" row wise and divide by length of "b" to get the mean

```
result = sum(c,2)/length(b);
```

You can simplify this for your exact example, but this is a generic solution for any vetors "a" and "b", where "b" is the smaller vector.

Comment: This work for example above, but code return error if for example I change vector b to be b = [1]' or b = [1 2 3]' or even b = [1 2 3 4]'. It return Subscripted assignment dimension mismatch.

Comment: You're right @Roki, good catch! I changed the definition of "c". It works now. Enjoy!

Comment: It works. Thanks. I curious if there is some other method solving the problem what is better time wised, if not, I will accept this answer as solved.

Comment: What are the average sizes you work with? Is "b" large? If "b" is somewhat small, the computations efficiency should be quite good. Otherwise I could take another crack at it.

Comment: I just tried the following:

`a = rand(1e6,1); b = rand(1e2,1);` and computed everything in 0.573916 seconds. (16 GB ram, Intel Core i7-4810MQ 2.80 GHz)

Comment: I work with "b" of value of 1k and "a" with value close to 10k. Yours program still do quite a good speed at this value rates, but if I need to expand vectors to bigger values, speed dramatically droping.
As your upper example, with a = rand(1e6,1); b = rand(1e2,1);  I get in 2.678378 seconds (4 GB ram and Pentium R Dual - Core E6500 2.93Ghz.

Comment: Hmm, I was considering using `arrayfun`, but I don't think it will make it faster. It's quite a lot of computations but I think the code you have now is quite fast. As long as `c` is declared prior to the for loop, as in the answer.